# In this schematic, where is the depleted layer once voltage is applied to the the sensor?

Tags: semiconductors, pn-junction

In the following schematic from
https://cds.cern.ch/record/2717863/files/CERN-THESIS-2019-340.pdf

the sensor is the top part, the readout electronic is the bottom.

Once we have applied an electric voltage, where is the depleted layer ?
(Is it in region of n-silicon and p+ ? Is it in region of (n+ of middle, n-silicon) and p+ ?)

[image]

Comment: I suggest that you read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_junction and then you should conclude that 1) the depletion region is the region surrounding the PN junction. If that's p, p+, n or n+ does not matter. What matters is p touching n. 2) the depletion region forms by itself, no external voltage needs to be applied.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie : You are right, the depletion region does not need external voltage (but it gets extended if we apply a reverse voltage). Actually, I have already followed a one year course on semiconductor physics, and read one book on semiconductors physics. But this didn't answer to my question about the "n+" and "n", "p+", "p". So you mean that the deplete region, without application of revert tension, covers a part of the "p+" and a part of the "n-silicon". I guess that without additional revert tension, there is no reason that it cover the "n" region. Do you agree ?

Comment: If we apply a revert tension of enough magnitude, will the depleted region also cover the n+ region ?

Comment: *I guess that without additional revert tension, there is no reason that it cover the "n" region. Do you agree ?* No, I disagree, as I said, the depletion zone exists at the p-n junction (here: around the "p+" and "n-Silicon" areas) and will be partly in the p-type region and partly in the n-type region. The depletion zone might not reach the **n+** region at the bottom of the sensor part. But that actually depends on doping concentrations, the actual sizes and applied voltages. So the depeletion region can extend down to the n+ region but it is unlikely due to the large n region.

Comment: @BimpelrekkieI : I made a typo : I was meaning that without revert voltage, there is no reason that is covert the *n+* region. ok, thank you for your explanation. Would you know where apply the external voltage ? I guess that the negative voltage should go to the aluminium of the top. But what about the negative voltage : should it be applied to the so-called "passivation" part ? Why ?

Comment: I was meaning : should the plus voltage go the the passivation part ? Why to the "passivation" part ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under a high fluence of charged particles in high energy physics accelerator experiment, the n bulk is type inverted, forming a p substrate on the n+ side, located at the bottom beside p-spray implants. Effectively, the p-n junction here (and the depletion zone, respectively) is p-substrate (inverted from n bulk) on n+ implant. This design with p-spray implants is used to achieve pixel separation required for high detector resolution. The upper p+ backside implant is common for all pixel.

When in operation, the depletion voltage applied to a pixel sensor depletes the whole upper-half chip of the detector (an "n on n sensor") and the depletion zone extends all the way from the top p+-n junction to the bottom n-n+ transition. Sure, there is no such thing as n+-n-junction, but, because of the n-bulk type-inversion, "the depletion zone is free of unbound charges due to recombination of the electron excess with hole excess between the n and p part", and further on following the Section **2.2 The Pixel Detector** of the document you cited in your question.

A quite unusual configuration of the depletion zone, isn't it?

As for the "passivation" mentioned in your comments, surface passivation is the part of the device fabrication process and refers to the chemistry of device materials. In the n-on-n sensor, the passivation layer is also important because we need a means to isolate edge of the substrate from a readout chip. The sensor is biased by a few hundred volt voltage and this significant voltage should be dropped across the passivation layer, from the p-side to the readout chip potential. The passivation layer must be of good quality to protect the device from breakdowns.

**UPDATE**: answers to comment questions

> What prevents, from physics laws, than the depleted region to continue
> in the full region of p+ and in the full region of n+ ?

Nothing prevents. In a bulk not damaged by irradiation the depletion voltage providing a 300um thick depletion zone can be as low as 50V. With the process of donor removal launched by the increasing fluence of the charged particles the depletion voltage even decreases and at ca. a few 10<sup>12</sup>cm<sup>-2</sup> fluence the donor removal by irradiation of the bulk results in a 300um thick depletion zone even with near-zero depletion voltage. With higher fluences, the radiation induced defects result in space charge accumulation and consequently lead to the type reversal of the bulk: an original n-type bulk becomes a p-type bulk. Radiation-induced charge accumulation outweighs the effect of dopants like phosphorus. The effective doping concentration is complicated by the **annealing** aftermath.

> do you mean that the "n-silicon" transforms to a part "p-effective"
> and a part "n-effective" ?

No, read it as is written: the process of donor removal launched by the increasing fluence of the charged particles can lead to the type reversal of the bulk: an original, without radiation induced defects, n-type bulk becomes a p-type bulk.

> Where do we apply the polarisation for the electronic readout (the
> bottom device below the "bump".

See @jonk's comment to your Q [Where can I find a clear analysis of how the krummenacher circuit works?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/564306/where-can-i-find-a-clear-analysis-of-how-the-krummenacher-circuit-works)

> What is the role of oxid ? What is the role of nitrid ?

Silicon oxide is a standard isolation material used in semiconductor devices. Silicon nitride, with its higher dielectric constant as compared to silicon oxide, is used as a second dielectric to increase the coupling of the signal to the readout electrodes (via "bumps").

You can find a more detailed explanations of semiconductor particle detector principles and implementations on the CERN Document Server (https://cds.cern.ch/record/368412), the SLAC site (https://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C020909/trpaper.pdf), and the DESY site ([https://www.desy.de/~schleper/lehre/Det_Dat/SS_2018/](https://www.desy.de/%7Eschleper/lehre/Det_Dat/SS_2018/)).

The recommended option to study particle detectors is to enroll in the school offering such courses. Also, you can try CERN's or SLAC's summer schools, they offer the remote learning.

Good luck with your studies!

Comment: My deep gratitude for your generous explanations. So what @Bimpelrekkie had not completely understood the structure (although it is a counterintuitive structure as you explain) : the depleted region is at the interface of N+ and "n-silicon" (and could extended further), it is not in the interface "p+ to n-silicon". ok. May I ask further questions... Could we call the "n+" part a "well" ? Why is the n+ typically much smaller than the substrate ? (why not having the n+ as thick as the substrate).

Comment: *When in operation, the depletion voltage applied to..* You mean: When in operation, a **reverse** voltage is applied to...

Comment: the "n+ part" is by no means a well, and not only because the device is not a transistor and so needs nor n-wells neither p-wells, but also because in transistors, p- and n-wells are not and cannot be highly doped regions. The highly doped regions in the MOSFET transistors connecting the source and drain terminals to the channel must be of the same type, p+ in PMOS and n+ in NMOS, and of **opposite** type to the well region, which is n-type for PMOS and p-type for NMOS.

Comment: Back to the pixel sensor: while in operation, the depleted zone "extends from the n - p transition to the bottom n on n transition", Section 2.2. Using wording of your comment, the depletion zone extends from 'the interface "p+ to n-silicon"' up to 'the interface of N+ and "n-silicon"' inclusive. There is no need of the thick n+ region, on the contrary, it must be kept small as possible. This region (in a sensor) is used only as a conductor that guides the collected charge to an aluminium bonding panel (in MOSFET it also takes part in level bending and is essential for transistor operation).

Comment: Again, "The depletion voltage applied to the back of the sensor therefore needs to be high enough to deplete the whole chip", Section 2.2. The depletion zone is the place where the high energy particles are detected, and it is detrimental for the device design to shrink the depletion zone by extending the n+ region into the n-type body. To easier understand the device operation, the n-on-n sensor can be compared to the photodiode (not a phototransistor!), only the incident photons in the n-on-n sensor generate electron-positron pairs instead of electron-hole pairs in a conventional photodiode.

Comment: First, Thank you again for all your help. I provided you a bounty to thank you. To summarize, in absence of polarisation, the depleted region is starting at the junction "(p+ ; n-silicon)" and finishes inside n-silicon, a bit lower to the junction (p+ ; n-silicon). In presence of reverse polarisation, the depleted region extends from the junction "(p+ ; n-silicon)" to the junction "(n-silicon ; n+)". What prevents, from physics laws, than the depleted region to continue in the full region of p+ and in the full region of n+ ? (the migration due to Fick law should still exist).

Comment: Also, do you mean that the "n-silicon" transforms to a part "p-effective" and a part "n-effective" ? Is the "n on n" contained in the "n-silicon" ?

Comment: Where do we apply the polarisation for the electronic readout (the bottom device below the "bump". We should see two places in order to polarise it, but I see no place on the schematic.

Comment: What is the role of oxid ? What is the role of nitrid ?

Comment: What prevents the depletion to appear between the n+ and p-spray ?

Comment: Read UPDATE in my answer. Good luck with your studies!