# How will new (n on n) pixel detector work at *beginning* of HL-LHC?

Tags: semiconductors, pn-junction

The pixel detector of ATLAS and CMS detector is expected to be replaced by a technology N in N, instead of N in P.

We see in the preferred answer of
[In this schematic, where is the depleted layer once voltage is applied to the the sensor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/564195/in-this-schematic-where-is-the-depleted-layer-once-voltage-is-applied-to-the-th)

that the idea is that the N substrate will be inverted (to P) under the high fluence of charged particles in the experiment, thus, the N substrate will at a given point transform to a doped P semiconductor, thus allowing to have the required PN junction in order to be able to detect particles.

My question is : at the *beginning* of HL-LHC, since the N substrate will not yet been inverted to a P, how could this detector work ? Should we wait some times to allow it to invert before the detector could be used ?

Also, one says that under high fluence of charged particle, the doping of a semiconductor reverts : that is : a doped N semiconductor for example transforms into a P.

But then, does it mean that at LHC, the N substrate will transform after a while to a P, and then later... this P will transform to a N, and so on ? If so, there would be a periodic change of behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

From the [linked thesis](https://cds.cern.ch/record/2717863/files/CERN-THESIS-2019-340.pdf), pp6-7 here is a quote:

> ...the depletion zone of which extends from the n - p transition to
> the bottom n on n transition. **The depletion voltage
> applied to the back of the sensor** therefore needs to be high enough to deplete the whole chip.

which means the depletion region is effectively the majority of the die thickness, and that there is a circuit that is actively applying a significant negative voltage on the top of the sensor pixel to maintain that depletion region. See the colored image below:

[image]

Now I couldn't find what the magnitude of that voltage is, or how exactly they connected to the back. However, through-silicon vias (TSV) are common enough that it would be my first guess, but even a wirebond to the back side would be *possible*. I've shown the bias voltage "virtually connected" to the N+ electrode, but that's a gross oversimplification of that thesis.

Addressing your specific questions:

> At the beginning of HL-LHC, since the N substrate will not yet been
> inverted to a P, how could this detector work? Should we wait some
> times to allow it to invert before the detector could be used?

"In the beginning" with the circuit unpowered, the electron-hole pairs will just recombine in place. Once the circuit is powered, the sensor will be biased, creating the depletion region with a voltage gradient.

> Also, one says that under high fluence of charged particle, the doping of a semiconductor reverts : that is : a doped N semiconductor for example transforms into a P.

That's not the dominant effect. The continuous DC voltage bias (and the material conductivity) ensures that the electron-hole pairs generated by the charged particles travel to the P+/N+ terminals instead of simply recombining in place. The "N-silicon" is likely to be lightly doped compared to the P+/N+ regions, meaning that the depletion region will extend much further through the wafer compared to the N+/P+ regions for a given bias voltage.

Comment: Thank you for your generosity for having given your kind explanations.